# How can I force a field to be enabled on the Bills and Adjustments screen's Document Details grid

Tags: acumatica

I'm currently trying to force a field to be enabled on the RowSelected event, which I've gotten to work before, but now it doesn't.

When a Bill is in a status where the grid is disabled, I have two added user fields that I want to remain enabled.

The code I'm using is this, which I thought would work:

```
    protected virtual void APTran_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var aptran = e.Row as APTran;
        if (aptran != null)
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrGrantID>(cache, aptran, true);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrReimbursementPeriod>(cache, aptran, true);
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably what is happening is that the view currently has the allow update set to false this overrides the enabled state which you are setting. One way to bypass this is that for that status you set the allow update to true. Then force the whole grid to be disabled apart from the two fields which you want. Example Below:

```
protect virtual void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row is APinvoice row)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            Transactions.Cache.AllowUpdate = true
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(Transactions.Cache, null, false);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrGrantID>(Transactions.Cache, null, true);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrReimbursementPeriod>(Transactions.Cache, null, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had seen that in another example - so I guess I have to set the allowupdate based on the status - sort of duplicating the existing business logic.   Thanks much, Jean Claude! ;D